# Why multiple projects created in Visual Studio Team Services depend on each other?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm new to Visual Studio Team Services, and created 2 sample project. I see 2 project names (say P1 and P2) on my dashboard page (section "Recent projects & teams"). I've expected for those projects to be completely independant.

But when I've checked them out in Visual Studio 2013 on desktop, added some code (TFS source control repository) and introduce some pending changes for each of the project, these changes are suggested as *single check in*. I of cause can exclude changes from one project, but... That was not all!

When I've created a Build definition and set it up as Gated check-in for P1 (accept change only after successful build), *the failed build from P1 does not allow to commit changes to P2*. It basically starts that Gated check-in trigger no matter to what project I'm committing.

So am I missing something? Some sort of setting or checkbox on the portal? I just want to make my 2 projects completely independant from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably setup your workspace to map both team projects.

For example, I can setup a workspace mapping like so:

```
|Server  |Local   |
|$/      |C:\Code |
```

And now I can check out any change in the **entire** Team Project Collection to `C:\Code`.

If you are after workspaces independent to a Team Project (or even a branch) use the "Workspaces" option from the combo box at the top of Source Control Explorer and create multiple workspaces each with a mapping relevant to the team project's root:

[image: Workspaces]

For example you might map 2 workspaces like this:

**Project 1 Workspace**

```
|Server  |Local     |
|$/P1/   |C:\P1Code |
```

**Project 2 Workspace**

```
|Server  |Local     |
|$/P2/   |C:\P2Code |
```

If you want to reuse folders on disk you could even have them both set to map to `C:\Code\P{n}`. That way `C:\Code` is not under source control, but `P1` and `P2` would be - this is my preference.

Comment: That approch worked, thanks. However I do not completelly understand all those workspaces, projects etc. (especially with this possibility to commit separatelly or in single commit). Could you suggest some links/sources to make this more clear?

Comment: Workspaces are a bit weird in TFS, it took me a while to get my head around. Basically it's a mapping of code locally, but it can be mapped at any level in the code hierarchy, and you can have multiple server and local paths. All changes in a workspace are tracked together. Try having a read of this from Martin Woodward: http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000333.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, it clarified some things)